# Como Obtener entidades reacionada con GORM en GO

Tags: go, gorm

Estoy realizando una rest con GO, usando GorrillaMux y GORM

Mi problema surge porque no logro hacer que me devuelva las entidades relacionados a una entidad principal.

Estas son las entidades en la base de datos

[image: Entidad en la base de datos]

Estas son las estructuras en GO con las anotaciones

```
type File struct {
IdFile          int         `gorm:"type:int(11);primary_key;unique_index;AUTO_INCREMENT;column:id_file" json:"idFile"`
Description     string      `gorm:"type:varchar(200);column:description" json:"decription"`
FileName        string      `gorm:"type:varchar(100);column:file_name" json:"fileName"`
FileExtension   string      `gorm:"type:varchar(10);column:file_extension" json:"fileExtension"`
FilePath        string      `gorm:"type:varchar(255);column:file_path" json:"filePath"`
Date            time.Time   `gorm:"type:datetime();column:date" json:"date"`
FileTypeID      int         `gorm:"type:int(11);column:id_document_type" json:"idFileType"`
FileType        FileType    `gorm:"references:FileTypeId" json:"fileType"`}

type FileType struct {
    ID              int         `gorm:"type:int(11);primary_key;unique_index;AUTO_INCREMENT;column:id_document_type" json:"idFileType"`
    TypeName        string      `gorm:"type:varchar(200);column:description" json:"description"`
}
```

y esta es la funcion en la que obtengo los "files" y los devuelvo

```
func GetFiles()[]model.File{
context := database.GetInstance()
var files []model.File
context.Db.Find(&files)
return files }
```

de todo esto la respuesta que obtengo de postman es

```
[
{
    "idFile": 55,
    "decription": "Archivo de Prueba 1",
    "fileName": "Test",
    "fileExtension": ".pdf",
    "filePath": "/home/user/Test.pdf",
    "date": "2020-01-02T00:00:00-03:00",
    "idFileType": 1,
    "fileType": {
        "idFileType": 0,
        "description": ""
    }
},
{
    "idFile": 56,
    "decription": "Archivo de Prueba 2",
    "fileName": "texto",
    "fileExtension": ".docx",
    "filePath": "/home/user/texto.dock",
    "date": "2020-10-02T00:00:00-03:00",
    "idFileType": 2,
    "fileType": {
        "idFileType": 0,
        "description": ""
    }
},
{
    "idFile": 57,
    "decription": "Archivo de Prueba 3",
    "fileName": "Planilla de calculo",
    "fileExtension": ".xls",
    "filePath": "/home/user/Planilla de calculo.xls",
    "date": "2020-03-19T00:00:00-03:00",
    "idFileType": 3,
    "fileType": {
        "idFileType": 0,
        "description": ""
    }
}]
```

Muchas gracias anticipadas

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar la función de GORM `Preload("Relation name")` para cargar las relaciones

En tú caso sería algo como

```
context.Db.Preload("FileType").Find(&files)
```

Documentación https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html

Saludos